# What is the correct way to have an optional self mutating function as a struct member?

Tags: rust

I want to do this:

```
struct Foo {
    id: u32,
    updater: Option<Fn(&mut Foo)>, // the Foo here should be self
}

impl Foo {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        if let Some(the_updater) = self.updater {
            the_updater(&mut self);
        }
    }
}
```

Is the intention here possible? What would the syntax look like for assigning to `Foo::updater`?

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function pointer:

```
struct Foo {
    id: u32,
    updater: Option<fn(&mut Foo)>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        if let Some(the_updater) = self.updater {
            the_updater(self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { id: 41, updater: None };
    foo.updater = Some(|foo| foo.id += 1);
    foo.update();

    println!("foo.id: {}", foo.id);
}
```

Here, a closure that doesn't capture anything is implicitly converted to a function and then used as a function pointer.

See also:

- [How to pass a member function of a struct to another struct as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43273971/155423)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if this seemed a trivial question – I was closer than I thought I was. I think `Fn` vs `fn` and the syntax of `a_foo.updater =  Some(|bar: &mut Foo| {})` was what confused me.