# How to Get Rust Member Function to Callback in Struct

Tags: rust, struct, callback

I've been trying to understand callback functions in Rust. After going through a few examples in stackoverflow, I still can't get it to run when the function I want to call is a member function of another struct.

My example is built upon this example post: [How to pass a member function of a struct to another struct as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273971/how-to-pass-a-member-function-of-a-struct-to-another-struct-as-callback)

```
struct Person {
    name: String
}

impl Person {
    pub fn print_name(&self) {
        println!("Hello from {}", self.name);
    }
}

struct Operation {
    cb: fn(&Person),
}

impl Operation {
    pub fn caller(&self) {
        (self.cb)()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        name: "Brad".to_string()
    };

    let op = Operation {
        cb: Person::print_name,
    };
    
    op.caller()
}
```

This example doesn't break the linter, but when I try to run it, I get errors about the type and arguments provided.

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         (self.cb)()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^-- supplied 0 arguments
   |         |
   |         expected 1 argument

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

It seems to me that it cant resolve the self variable so it makes me wonder why the example in the previous post was accepted if that structs function can't actually be called.

Comment: *"why the example in the previous post was accepted if that structs function can't actually be called"* - it can be called, you simply have to pass in the object to call it on. The linked question doesn't bind the function to the particular object.

Comment: @kmdreko I guess I need to ask how do I pass in the object to that function call? When I try in `op.caller(person)` this fails as well. Do I have to initialize the struct with that object instace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your struct definition, you are saying that the function stored in `cb` takes a `&Person` argument, so you need to make sure that argument is passed along whenever you try to call the function. You should change the `caller` method to handle the argument like so:

```rust
struct Person {
    name: String
}

impl Person {
    pub fn print_name(&self) {
        println!("Hello from {}", self.name);
    }
}

struct Operation {
    cb: Box<dyn Fn()>,
}

impl Operation {
    pub fn caller(&self) {
        (self.cb)()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        name: "Brad".to_string()
    };

    let op = Operation {
        cb: Box::new(move || person.print_name()),
    };
    
    // person is no longer available here because it has been moved into `op.cp`
    //dbg!(person.name); // this will fail
    
    op.caller();
}
```

Comment: another option may be to use a closure so that the function in `cb` has access to the variables which were in scope at its creation, but that may not be what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you. This will get this example working. Is it possible to bind one specific object/struct to the callback? IMO, this method does not hide the person behind the Operation abstraction the way I would desire.

Comment: @luvguru69 do you mean you want a function that *only* accepts the created `person`, as opposed to any `Person` struct?

Comment: that is correct. That is the implementation I'm working towards.

Comment: @luvguru69 I updated the answer to include a closure that captures `person`. It is no longer technically storing `Person::print_name`, but storing a new function that calls `person.print_name()`.

Comment: thank you for this. I just implemented this into my more complicated use case and it worked perfectly!